# Using openwith (or alternative) on Mac

Tags: openwith

My `openwith-associations` includes:

```
("\\.xlsx\\'" "Microsoft Excel"
  (file)))
```

But this doesn't work. How should this association be written? Is there a better way to open the file link at point than using `openwith`?

Comment: what is the command name to open excel from the terminal on macs? I suspect it's not two words? On linux I use "localc", not "LibreOffice Calc"

Answer (score 1):

The shell command is just `open`, which makes `openwith` very handy indeed.

```
("\\.xlsx\\'" "open"
  (file)))
```